# Почему элемент выглядит как блочный?

Tags: html, css

Есть flex контейнер, в котором находятся input и кнопка.
Почему-то при заданных `flex-shrink` и `flex-grow` контейнер расстягивается на всю ширину окна.

Как исправить данную ситуацию?

HTML

```
<div class="resizePopUp popUp">
    <input type="range" class="width">

    <div class="openHide">
        <img src="../img/icons/chevron left-right.svg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.resizePopUp {
  background: #2F2F2F;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-grow: 0;


  .openHide {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;

    display: grid;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что это стандартное поведение для контейнеров — занимать всю доступную ширину. Стили flex-shrink и flex-grow относятся только к элементам внутри контейнера, а не к самому́ контейнеру

Comment: Если вы хотите, чтобы контейнер занимал минимально возможную ширину, то используйте `display: inline-flex` например?